# Should I *really* be calling DataBind()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, lifecycle

I have a CustomControl that, when used on a page, needs to take as a property a value from a server-side value. I tried this ...

```
<MyControl runat="server"
           ID="MyControl1"
           ContainerId="<%= this.ClientID %>" />
```

Now, when run (for the sake of this explanation, lets say that I know the value of `this.ClientID` was "ctl00_MyControl1") if I test the value, client-side, of `ContainerId` it comes back as "<%= this.ClientID %>".

Without really understanding why, I tried this instead...

```
<MyControl runat="server"
           ID="MyControl1"
           ContainerId="<%# this.ClientID %>" />
```

But testing the value of `ContainerId` showed that the value was empty!

Some more reading enabled me to see that the <%# %> mechanism is for data binding but, clearly, my control wasn't doing that (assume that my CustomControl inherits from a TextBox).

So, I added a call to `DataBind()` to the `OnLoad` event of the UserControl that my CustomControl is contained in.

Yay! It worked. However, when processing certain events on the Page, the call to `DataBind()` generates an exception. The exception is in another control, contained in the same UserControl container as `MyControl1`.

The message is

```
Selection out of range
Parameter name: value
```

and the stack trace finishes like this ...

```
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable dataSource)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data)
   at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.PerformSelect()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.DataBind()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind()
```

Now, I'm **not** looking for a solution to this exception; I've included it to demonstrate that I believe that my calling `DataBind()` is not necessarily the right thing to do.

So, Questions:

1. Why doesn't <%= %> give the value at runtime I expect?
2. Is calling `DataBind()` whenever the UserControl's `OnLoad` event fires the right thing to do to get my value at runtime and, if it is,
3. Are there conditions I should be checking for before calling `DataBind()`

Comment: I'm not sure of the best solution for you, but afaik, doing `<%=...%>` is analogous to `Response.Write`, which wouldn't make sense in the context you're using.

Comment: A blog post on the difference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2007/02/13/the-difference-between-lt-and-lt-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that; I recall reading that about <%= %> now, I guess it just didn't stick!

Comment: Useful link. So, in short I can use <%= for non-server controls and <%# for server controls but only if `DataBind()` gets called somewhere along the line. I guess I just need to figure out the **right** way to call it! Thx again.

Comment: Your user control doesn't _need_ a value from the codebehind. It has a property, which the page it's on wants to set to a value from the codebehind of that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"`<%= this.ClientID %>`"
```

is called at render time and `ClientID` has not been set at that moment.

```
"`<%# this.ClientID %>`"
```

is called during the control or page `DataBind()`. 
If you are going to use this last one, then you should indeed call `DataBind()` and fix your exception.

Comment: Your two examples are identical. Didn't you mean the second one to be `<%# this.ClientID %>`?

Comment: For some reason, the exception is throw if I call `DataBind()` on _every_ call to `OnLoad()`, but if I only execute it when `!IsPostBack` all is fine. I don't claim to understand why, but that, I guess is a subject for another place.